# Linux kernel - add system call dynamically through module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

Is there any way to add a system call dynamic, such as through a module? I have found places where I can override an existing system call with a module by just changing the `sys_call_table[]` array to get my overridden function instead of the native when my module is installed, but can you do this with a new system call and a module?

Comment: I always thought that adding system calls was a nono, but that's just hearsay.

Comment: Yes, adding system calls is sort of useless for a rootkit :)

Comment: Adding a syscall is definitely not supported. It's likely you want a new solution to your problem. Why do you feel you need a new syscall anyway?

Answer (score 12):

No, `sys_call_table` is of fixed size:

```
const sys_call_ptr_t sys_call_table[__NR_syscall_max+1] = { ...
```

The best you can do, as you probably already discovered, is to [intercept](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4378) existing system calls.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've decided to intercept.

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting existing system call (to have something done in the kernel) is not the right way in some cases.   For eg, if your userspace drivers need to execute something in kernel, send something there, or read something from kernel?

Usually for drivers, the right way is to use ioctl() call, which is just one system call, but it can call different kernel functions or driver modules - by passing different parameters through ioctl().

The above is for user-controlled kernel code execution.

For data passing, you can use procfs, or sysfs drivers to talk to the kernel.

PS:   when you intercept system call, which generally affect the entire OS, you have to worry about how to solve the problem of doing it safely:   what if someone else is halfway calling the system call, and then you modify/intercept the codes?